# Clarification the function of coefficient of Post variable in DID for two-year two-group

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference, explanatory-models

When reading [a paper about DiD](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev-publhealth-040617-013507), I saw a sentence describing the function of the $Post_t$ variable in DiD for two groups and two periods:

> In a similar manner, the coefficient on $P_t$ captures the combined effects of any unmeasured covariates that change between the two periods but affect outcomes the same way in both groups

$P_t$ is the $Post_t$ variable in a standard DiD setting.

In the sentence above, I get lost regarding the phrase "**unmeasured covariates that change between the two
periods but affect outcomes the same way in both groups**."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post-treatment variable $P_t$ is unit-invariant. Put different, it is fixed across units. Note how the variable in this setting exhibits the same “within-unit” pattern. It’s capturing the “time trend” as cases/units evolve from pre- to post-treatment. If viewed as a deviation from a unit mean, it will actually remove (i.e., ‘difference out’) any unmeasured confounders fixed across units. In applied work, it is routinely regarded as modeling the shocks common across all your $i$ units.